# how to upload video to youtbue using YouTube Direct Lite App for Android

Tags: android, maven, youtube-api, google-api-java-client

i'm try to upload video from youtube without using intent

in my previous Q 
[using youtube data in android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324240/using-youtube-data-in-android-project)

Ibrahim Ulukaya Proposed to use in his example  https://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/

at the time i add the project i receive message " built path contains duplicate entry 'src' for project "Youtube Direct ..."

this after i  Include Google Play Services library to the project (this fix the all compile error exapt this "Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: resources.arsc")

in some form i saw that problem cause from marven plug in 
so i add  m2eclipse plugin maven-android-plugin

but i dont understand after i red marvel introdution **what marvel do and for what the project need this plug in ???**

Currently I am in state that I can not even start the project because of compilation problem.
**Someone was in this situation and know what I need to do for resolve this and start working with the project???**

Ibrahim Ulukaya told me that i don't need the whole project, i can just use UploadService.java and ResumableUpload.java.
so I deleted the other files but did not help

Answer (score 1):

I think Maven is a really good tool, but if you want you can create an Eclipse Android project without Maven, that is simpler. Then copy the code from the src folder and resources from the res folder.

You must include Google Play Services and the latest YouTube client library for Android with its dependencies:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#YouTube_Data_API